# Hosting a small website using IIS / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, web-hosting

I am looking to host a small site for some video content. I konw some C# and ASP.NET so this would be my lanugage of choice.
Question is, if I can build it all using express . free editions of VS, SQL Server and IIS, am I allowed to publish this on the internet for people to view? Not making profit, just my own music performances. I dont need to worry about buying a commercial edition?

Thanks.

John

Comment: Yes, you can - that's within the license terms as I recall. Check the latest version before depending on what definitely isn't legal advice from random guy on SO though :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!  The community addition is more than capable to meet your needs.  You could even host the site for free on Azure if you wanted:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/pricing-offers/

Although the database hosting would cost unless you used a file based database like SQLite.